# fetch post always pass null to the parameters

Tags: react-native

There's a fetch post with "userid" as a parameter. I've tested the url and parameter in native android, it works there but here it doesn't take the parameter. It always sends the null value to "userid" parameter. Am I doing smthing wrong here?

```
fetch('http://zzz.com/zzz/api/battery/gpswithbattery', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        userid: '404',
    })
})
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        console.log(responseJson);
         //return responseJson.message;
        this.setState({
            data: responseJson.message
        })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I see no mistake you are doing here, and start using es7 syntax, as that'll be even cleaner and easy to find mistakes, 
pro-tip: use prettier that'll make to look your code better.

```
  const method = async () => {
    const reponse = await fetch("http://zzz.com/zzz/api/battery/gpswithbattery", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        userid: "404"
      })
    });
    const responseJson = await response.json();
    this.setState({ data: responseJson.message });
  };
```